# Reload Page with added parameter

Tags: jquery, user, online

I have created a Page in SharePoint online and it contains an embed code from another service that we utilize. I want this service to track the user that viewed the page within the embed. To do this, I need to add "?id=usersemailaddress" to the URL AFTER the user has launched the page. I am using the code below, but it fails at `window.history.pushstate`. 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(function() {
  document.title = "Custom Title";
  $( "#ctl00_fullscreenmodeBtn" ).hide();
});
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext',function(){  
  var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web = context.get_web();
  var currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
  context.load(currentUser);
  context.executeQueryAsync(
  function(){
    console.log(currentUser.get_email()); 
      if (window.location.href  === "https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/test/SitePages/test.aspx") {
         window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/test/SitePages/test.aspx?id=" + currentUser.get_email());
      }
    }, 
  function(sender, args){
    console.log('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
  });
});
```

Comment: wouldn't you just do a `window.location.href = "https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/test/SitePages/test.aspx?id=" + currentUser.get_email());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try this :

```
var url = window.location.href;    
if (url.indexOf('?') > -1){
   url += '&param=1'
}else{
   url += '?param=1'
}
window.location.href = url;
```

Comment: I've tried this and it isn't quite working. I added a console.log(url) inside the else statement (which is the one that will fire almost 100% of the time for my scenario) and it logs the updated url with my parameter added properly. However, the page does not reload with this parameter.

Comment: can you please mention what "window.location.href" returns ?

Comment: After much trial and error, I figured out that the embed code I was using with the page had to be in a script web part BELOW the code I was using to reload the page. Something in the vendors embed code was causing a javascript error that halted the reload.